# Is unit testing of mongodb dynamic attributes possible in Grails 2.2?

Tags: unit-testing, mongodb, grails, grails-orm

It seems docs for mongodb-1.1.0GA are outdated when it comes to unit testing section: http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/ref/Testing/DatastoreUnitTestMixin.html

Following code

```
@TestFor(Employee)
class EmployeeTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    void setUp() {
    }

    void tearDown() {
    }

    void testSomething() {
        mockDomain(Employee)

        def s = new Employee(firstName: "first name", lastName: "last Name", occupation: "whatever")
        s['testField'] = "testValue"
        s.save()

        assert s.id != null

        s = Employee.get(s.id)

        assert s != null
        assert s.firstName == "first name"
        assert s['testField'] == "testValue"

    }
}
```

fails with this error:

```
No such property: testField for class: Employee
```

Employee class is pretty straightforward:

```
class Employee {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String occupation


    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false, nullable: false
        lastName blank: false, nullable: false
        occupation blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

So, is unit testing of dynamic attributes possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no out of the box support for dynamic attributes but it's fairly easy to add. I've put the following code in my setup method. It will add dynamic attributes to any domain classes you have enabled using `@TestFor` or `@Mock`.

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { domainClass ->
    domainClass.metaClass.with {
        dynamicAttributes = [:]
        propertyMissing = { String name ->
            delegate.dynamicAttributes[name]
        }
        propertyMissing = { String name, value ->
            delegate.dynamicAttributes[name] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it create something that is static? I get the same value for all items if i set it for one!

Comment: Yep my mistake. Using a `for` loop with do that (I blogged about why here http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/) I'll update the answer

Comment: I've edited your answer!, that worked for me! Feel free to approve or reject my answer! And i think u better update ur blog too!

Comment: I don't understand. I edited it already & the blog contains the right information.

Comment: This particular solution doesn't work! when one instance is changed the all the instances of that domain class are changed! Here see my question and also my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312245/metaclass-deligate-not-being-instance

Comment: It doesn't work when it uses a `for` loop (which I had in my original answer) but it does when using `each`.